# is Cov(X) and Var(X) same? when X is random vector

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, random-variables

i'm studying with hogg. introduction to mathematical statistics.

and i learned about random vector

but i wonder whether Cov(X) and Var(X) is same or not.

as intuitive thinking , if X is a random vector , say, X = (X$_1$, X$_2$, X$_3$, $...$ , X$_n$)$^t$

i just thought Cov(X) ( written as in text book) can be written as Var(X)

Is writing Var(X) wrong when X is a random vector or is there another meaning different from Cov(X)?

Comment: How does the text box write it?  We do not all have a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both "Cov" and "Var" are used to represent the covariance matrix of the vector $\bf X$. See for example [this Wikipedia remark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Conflicting_nomenclatures_and_notations):

> Nomenclatures differ. Some statisticians, following the probabilist William Feller, call the matrix $\Sigma$ the variance of the random vector X, because it is the natural generalization to higher dimensions of the 1-dimensional variance. Others call it the covariance matrix, because it is the matrix of covariances between the scalar components of the vector X.